# Javascript: Using a string to acces objects property

Tags: javascript, string, object

If I have a string like

```
var s = someString;
```

But I do NOT know the value of that string, since the program obtains it from external file, and I wanted to use that string to access an objects property, like:

```
alert(obj.s)

//or

alert(obj[s]);
```

How would I do that? The code I wrote doesn't work, the alerts are just empty (and I'm positive that `s` is NOT empty AND that there is a property with the same value as `s`). But when I try to access an object normally it works fine (using a property name I already know):

```
alert(obj.name); 
//or
alert(obj["name"]);
```

So...any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `obj.name` and `obj["name"]` would be the same as `obj[s]`, if `s` actually contained the string value `name`. If that “doesn’t work” for you, then your mistake is somewhere else. So show relevant parts of the actual problematic code please.

Comment: Are you sure that what is in the string is actually what you think is in the string? `console.log("myStringValue"===s); console.log(escape(s));`

Comment: "I'm positive that s is NOT empty AND that there is a property with the same value as s"-- don't you mean the same *name* as `s`? Property indexers go by name.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code and your assumptions are correct... you definitely have an issue somewhere else

Comment: Use JSON.stringify to know the pattern and then access it